# Recommend a source for ASP.NET templates?

Tags: asp.net, templates

I am going to build a basic small business site for myself and would like to get a head start with a quality ASP.NET template and don't mind purchasing one.

Can you recommend a reputable site I might check out for this?

Comment: Good points -- thank you all.

Comment: You can find good resources like some templates made for ASP.NET MVC that use MDBootstrap (a front-end framework built on top of Bootstrap) here: https://mdbootstrap.com/articles/miscellaneous/ready-to-use-asp-net-mvc-templates-from-mdb-and-how-to-integrate-them/

Answer (score 3):

not specifically asp.net but http://www.themeforest.net have some good themes which could easily be used in asp.net

Comment: Seconded on themeforest. Make sure you buy an html template. The companion site GraphicRiver.net has a lot of eye candy treatments like background colors, download now buttons, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think you would need to know what exactly you are going to do. If you are just after a web page template then look at [a css web page template](http://www.freecsstemplates.org/)

If you are planning  to have some sort of specific functionality and interactivity then how about [Kentico](http://www.kentico.com/) which is a CMS system.

Failing that, there are a good few choices if you download the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)

Regards,
Dom

Answer (score 0):

Although Wordpress is used more for blogging and not asp.net, I like the aesthetics of its available themes and you can easily port them an asp.net:

http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/

Not a template site, but this gave me ideas and inspiration:

http://ecommercegallery.com/